# Testing: When writing a HTTP response to the socket, write the headers, then sleep before writing the body

Tags: jetty

This is surely a weird one ... I'm doing some extreme integration style testing on a custom Java HTTP client for a backend service I'm working with. For reasons which don't matter here, the client has some specific quirks and a custom solution was the only real option.

For automated testing, I've built a "fake" version of the backend service by spinning up a Jetty server locally and having it behave in different ways e.g. return 500, wait e.g. 4 seconds before giving a response to simulate latency etc and firing off a battery of tests against it with the client on build time.

Given the nature of this client, there is an usual and specific scenario which I need to test and I'm trying to find a way to make my Jetty serve behave in the correct fashion. Basically, when returning HTTP response, I need to immediately return the HTTP Headers and the first few bytes of the HTTP body and then sleep. The goal is to trigger a socket timeout in the client specifically when reading the HTTP body.

Anyone know where in Jetty I could plug something in to force this behaviour? Was looking at the Connector interface but not so sure thats the right place.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a few bytes to the `HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()`, then call `HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer()` to immediately commit the response.

Bonus tip: use `HttpServletResponse.sendError(-1)` to terminate the connection abruptly.